Ошибка при подключении библиотеки - ld: library 'check' not found

Я скачал и установил библиотеку check через port |
Полный адрес до библиотеки /opt/local/lib
Указал путь к библиотеке: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Подключил библиотеку указав полный путь(иначе не видит):  #include </opt/local/include/check.h>
Попытался запустить OPENSTAT % gcc-14 -o prog hello.c

И получил ошибку:
-L/Users/artemdukup/OPENSTAT  -I/opt/local/include/ -lmain -lcheck
ld: library 'check' not found
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 

Не могу понять как её исправить и почему она возникает.
Если это важно у меня - Mac M1 AIR

файл check.h, судя по суффиксу в имени - это явно не библиотека, а всего лишь текстовый файл с заголовками. загрузчик же пишет вам о том, что не может найти библиотеку (т.е., собвственно, реализацию тех функций, которые упомянуты в файле с заголовками).

пробовал и через export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ошибка такая-же

ну так в /opt/local/lib у вас есть файл с библиотекой?

да там есть /opt/local/lib/libcheck.0.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libcheck.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libcheck.a

Все вопрос решил , спасибо большое, за верное направление, Александр !
